# How to add script tag with xlink:href attribute in svg file using android

Tags: javascript, android, svg

I am loading svg file from sdcard into webview. now I want to inject javascript file but its not working somehow. below is my code:

```
private void injectScriptFile(WevView view) {

          try {
                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                          "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('svg').item(0);" +
                          "var script = document.createElementNS('script');" +
                          "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
              "script.src = 'file:///android_asset/javascript_test.js';" +
                          "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                          "})()");
          } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
```

I also tried using 'xlink:href' attribute in stand of 'src' attribute but still same problem.

Comment: SVG script elements must be created with createElementNS the first argument of that needs to be the SVG namespace. Does that fix your issue?

Comment: I also tried that. but still not working..you can see my edited question.

Comment: **the first argument of that needs to be the SVG namespace**

Comment: @RobertLongson can you help me with that how to use.? I am totally unaware about javascript and SVG usage..